# If we find questions to Shanghai where should we leave a link for mods to find them?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, migration

I suggested for this person to join us but they only know about SO.

See: [distributed alpha beta pruning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9982870/1243762)

Can a mod Shanghai them.

It's seems like more of a pirate thing here than Shanghai.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only a moderator on the original site can migrate such a question. You have two options:

- Flagging the question. The moderator will see this and can react appropriately. *This may be annoying for some moderators, who may feel that you are stealing the questions from their site.*
- Commenting on the question. This is what you have done on the linked question. *This then leaves the choice to migrate in the hands of the OP. It's also good advertisement for our site, so long as you do it wisely/sparingly.*

---

As this cs.SE is an international site, it's probably a good idea to avoid using slang (especially relatively obscure slang). Otherwise people won't grok what you're saying.

Comment: sorry to go off-topic, but do you know where that slang is from?

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev: From the former custom of kidnapping men to man ships going to China. Not sure where from. England?